# write super script string in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

While ploting the data using matplotlib, I need to write the superscript string for 2 in m2. How can I do it?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x = [1,3,5,7,9,10,12]
y = [2,5,6,3,9,11,4]

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.xlabel('x (m2)')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Comment: When you googled for `matplotlib superscript` and [the docs](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html#subscripts-and-superscripts) came up as the first hit, what went wrong when you tried it?

Comment: @DSM, but the goal of SO is to make sure _this_ is the first hit

Comment: @ DSM i could not make use of it! how to input ^ for superscript when really writing the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use unicode strings

```
plt.xlabel(u'x (m²)')
plt.xlabel(u'y')
```

Using

```
plt.xlabel('x (m$^2$)')
```

gives a slightly different result - the <sup>2</sup> looks kind of weedy compared to the unicode version.

Comment: but the question is how did you typed m² when writing your code? @gnibbler

Comment: With a unicode keyboard or course! Don't forget to [specify an encoding for the source file](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code)

Comment: sorry i could not understand really what you pressed in your keyword to write m²? @ gnibbler

Comment: thanks i got it, but what is really the meaning of $ @ gnibbler

Comment: @nils What you press depends on which computer you are on. What did you press to write m² in your comment? You can do the same in your source code.

Comment: @kqr yes, i can directly input m² into my source code. but i do not know how to type m² (i am now using copy and paste) , i can type only m2.

Comment: The normal way of entering ² somewhere is by copying and pasting. (Or inserting from the Windows character table or your operating systems equivalent.) There is no special keyboard that has an extra ² key that everyone but you own. If you are writing ² very often you might want to customise your keymap to include it, but I would stick with copying and pasting otherwise.